# FFT Beat Detection Circuit

Tags: arduino, audio, sound, dsp, fft

I have for over a year now tried to figure out both the electronic aspect and the software aspect of my project.

I have somewhat successfully managed to make the overall idea to work,
the bumps I have come along the way are quite frankly stressing me out.

**Project description and goal:**

Basically a beat-detection device with a very small formfactor.

I am using an Arduino Uno as a prototyping device,
but I have an Arduino Mega, Sparkfun Micro and several other development boards
it stock to use if needed.

I want the microcontroller to read analog audio, convert it to FFT or FHT or
any other easily translated data, read the lower frequencies where the Kick of the
music is presented, and finally measure the timing between each kick to
calculate the BPM of the song.

The frequency range of where the Kick in the music is present is
around the 45Hz to 55Hz range and is most distinguishable in that area
when looking at it in a spectrum analyzer.

This should also be correct when doing FFT/FHT with a microcontroller
due to the nature of raw analog to digital to FFT/FHT conversion.

However, it may differ and is most likely to differ if a microphone is used
to listen to the audio.

**What I have successfully accomplished:**

- Assembling a circuit which allows for audio to be injected to an analog input of the arduino. The circuit can be found here:

[image: block diagram]
<sub>(source: [interface.khm.de](http://interface.khm.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/arduinoaudiofig1.gif))</sub>

- Implementing Open Music Labs FHT library to convert the analog audio to a frequency spectrum. The library can be found here: http://wiki.openmusiclabs.com/wiki/ArduinoFHT

So the two most important components of the project is in place.

**What I have problems with:**

- I get a constant peak in the lower frequency area of the spectrum which is present at all times. This is a problem because the Kick of the music is in that area.

**Things I have tried:**

- A guy on youtube tried to help me out by giving me simple instructions and he told me to use a 1uF capacitor between the Audio Surce and the Analog input, as well as trying either a pull-up or a pull-down resistor on the Analog Input.

Results (quote):

> When using  a pull-up, the low freq peak increases, when using a
> pull-down, the low freq disappears.
>
> So the Pull-down is the way to go.
>
> HOWEVER, with the pull-down present, harmonics of the sinus tone is
> introduced but no peak at the lower freq area as long as no sound is
> present.
>
> With the pull-down NOT present, the harmonics vanish, but the peak is
> present.

- Implementing FIR and IIR filters. Results: Audio still reacting to all frequencies.

**What more can I try before I throw this project out the window?**

Approaches and suggestions need to be component-limited and preferably software oriented.

The light organ needs to have low power consumption and very few physical components,
and if physical components are required, they need to be tiny and surface mounted.

Comment: A kick drum actually contains the spectrum of a snare drum (100s to several kHz) immediately followed by a decaying sub 100Hz spectrum so your analysis may be getting off on the wrong track to start off with.

Comment: What is your sample rate on the ADC, and how many samples are you using in your transform? It's entirely possible that you've got the wrong parameters.

Comment: @Andy I am using professional audio interface with a software which read live FFT, and the kick drum can vary in frequency range, yes, but the ultimate range is around 45 Hz, as that is the loudest frequency for a kick drum, at least for electronic dance music.

Comment: the sample rate is whatever Open Music Labs claims it to be, I'm using their stock code.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I tried your suggestion and changed the parameter LOG_OUT to LIN_OUT8 in combination with the answer that AaronD provided, and now I get a clean spectrum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the youtube guy might have been on the right track, but the confusion is that "ground" is typically centered between two supplies for most analog circuits, and coexistent with the lower supply for most digital circuits.  So whether you pulled it up or down, the DC level was already clipped, and so anything added to that (your music) was also clipped automatically.

Instead, you need to pull it to a point halfway in between.  The easiest way to do that is to simply pull it up and down at the same time, using two resistors.  That should center it nicely, with the exact level being determined by the ratio of the two resistors.

Also to consider:

- The cutoff frequency is 1 / (2 * pi * R * C) in hertz, where R is the parallel combination of the two resistors in ohms and C is the capacitor in farads.  You'll want to be about 1/10 of the lowest frequency that you want to detect.
- The two resistors in parallel (and the one resistor that you used before) will load down the audio source.  If it's greater than a few kohms, I wouldn't worry about it.
- The two resistors in series will draw current from the power supply.  If you're running from the wall and you've satisfied the previous point, that won't be a problem.  Batteries might be different.

---

### Update:

From a rather long discussion in the comments and a link to a different forum (http://www.openmusiclabs.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=493&sid=c89646aea90012eb0fbcbf4161ab5b74), it seems that the problem has to do with DC offset.  The original schematic attempts to solve this, but it includes an unnecessary adjustment that is easy to get wrong.  Here's a better way to do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcQ68q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Make sure to keep R1 and R2 equal.  The cutoff frequency is described above.

The purpose of the original adjustment seems to be to fine-tune the DC offset to match the ADC, but I expect enough variation from other sources that it's easier to just make it close and use a digital highpass to finish the job.

Some other changes:

- I switched to 10k resistors instead of 100k.  This provides a lower source impedance to the ADC for the DC level.  This requires a bigger cap for the same cutoff, which usually isn't a problem.
- I added a resistor to complete the basic anti-alias filter.  Use the same equation for cutoff frequency to put it about twice the highest frequency that you care about (10x would be better, but that may be asking too much of the ADC with this kind of filter), then run the ADC at least 10x the cutoff frequency.

As shown, the cutoff frequencies are ~1.5Hz and ~48kHz, so you'll want to get around to sampling that ADC channel at least 500kHz.  Why not 48kHz like standard audio?  Because this filter rolls off very slowly.  Only at much higher frequencies does it finally attenuate noise enough to not mess with your signal when shifted down by aliasing.  If you don't want to run the FHT that fast, you can use a more complex analog lowpass, or you can use a digital lowpass running that fast followed by throwing away most of the samples.

Comment: So basically the diagram I referred to that has a series of components on the left side of the diagram, is kind of correct, but not completely correct depending on the minimum frequency I want to detect?

Also, what you are suggesting with both a pullup and a pulldown, isn't that what the diagram is suggesting?

As I noted in the question, the youtube guy is on the right track but, harmonics are introduced in to the spectrum which makes the spectrum cluttered.

So a 1kHz sine wave is going to show up at 0Hz, 1kHz, 2kHz etc etc, that is not the case when the pull-down isn't present.

Comment: @xaid: You probably don't need the pot, but it looks good otherwise.  It's about a decade lower than it needs to be for audio (~0.3Hz), but that's probably fine.  That being said, there's something clearly wrong with the analog input components somewhere because you didn't change the software and you get a difference in distortion depending on how the analog stuff is configured.  RC circuits don't add harmonics like that; clipping does.

Comment: Or, maybe the source volume is too high.  That could clip too.

Comment: By the way, if you plan on using the analog audio output, you'll want a cap in series between the lowpass and the connector, to remove the 1/2 supply offset.  Then pull that down as an RC highpass.  Source impedance in the passband remains roughly equal to the lowpass R by itself.

Comment: I am not going to use the analog audio output.

You are correct about the clipping.
If I crank up the volume, harmonics do get introduced.

I have found a good volume level to experiment with.

The low freq constant peak is still there.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: @xaid: Is it actually a peak?  Or a simple DC offset?  You probably want a digital highpass anyway just to remove whatever slow variation there might be in the DC level.  I wouldn't trust an analog circuit to stay *exactly* at 1/2 scale of your ADC.

Comment: That being said, there is a 4.7nF cap in the diagram that will work with whatever source impedance you plug into it to make an analog lowpass.  It's probably for anti-aliasing, but a high source impedance could bring the cutoff into the audio band.

Comment: ...and a low source impedance might push it above the Nyquist frequency, at which point the spectrum "folds back" towards 0Hz as reported by the ADC.  If that's the problem, then you're sampling too slowly, and your low-frequency peak is actually high-frequency physically.

Comment: Yes it is a peak. I played with different resistor values and for example when hooking a potentiometer (10k) between +5v and the 10k resistor (replacing the upper 100k resistor), I can see a slight change in the peak as I turn the potentiometer. I am guessing that that has to do with the DC offset.

Comment: The diagram shows 100k-10k-100k between +5V and 0V.  You just called it a 10k resistor.  What did you actually do?

Comment: What I did was to change the +5v 100k resistor connection, so it looks like this : 10kPOT-10k-100k.

Comment: Okay, I see what you did.  At the most optimal setting, you have the equivalent of 20k-100k, when you really need equal values.  You don't need the pot; just use two fixed resistors of equal values that satisfy the requirements in my original post.  Then use a digital highpass between ADC and FHT.

Comment: I found this thread at the Open Music Lab forum, they speak about that low freq-peak that I'm having problems with: http://www.openmusiclabs.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=493&sid=c89646aea90012eb0fbcbf4161ab5b74

Comment: However I don't know where they've connected the potentiometer that they are mentioning.

Comment: DELETE THE POT!!!!  You don't need it!  Just connect two equal values in series across the power supply and connect the signal to the point between the resistors.  Add a digital highpass and you're done!  I'll update my answer with a diagram.

Comment: Alright alright take it easy hahaha. I think they used the pot to even out the DC offset, and I believe that the DC offset is what I referred to as Harmonics. But, in the forum thread they mentioned that they managed to get Bin 0 (the constant low freq peak) to even out as well. I am amazingly confused right now. Why wont it just work? I'm following each and every step as closely as I possibly can.

Comment: @xaid: Does that clear things up?

Comment: I'm trying it out. Your diagram failed. Kind of.
I removed the 22uF Capacitor, connected the audio IN signal directly to the connection where the Pullup and Pulldown is, and GREAT SUCCESS!

Please edit the diagram and we should be set.

Please also add to your answer that an amplifier should be used. I'm only get a relatively small spectrum amplitude.

Could any of the passive components have anything to do with that?

Comment: Oops. I am kind of wrong. When using AnalogRead() to get samples, your diagram WITHOUT the 22uF cap gives excellent results, but fairly low amplitude on the spectrum.

However, when using Open Music Labs original code, the 22uF cap lowers the low frequency peak, but gives higher spectrum amplitude.

I guess it has to do a little bit with sample rate as well.

Comment: Just noticed that I am using a 3.3uF cap instead of a 3.3nF cap. Unfortunately I don't have a 3.3nF cap, so I removed it alltogether ant the noise level + peak is still present, BUT, the audio signal seems to be a lot louder on the spectrum, so I can really distinguish the kick in the music, regardless genre, which is great. If only the noise could be deleted! That would be great!

Comment: Sounds like you still have a problem with the DC offset, and you are just guessing about the cause and possible fixes.  If you have a oscilloscope, you could measure the offset (might be able to use a voltmeter if there's no audio present.)  Find out what the DC offset is.  Check the input range of the ADC - it might be 0 to 5V, or it might be 0 to 3.3V or soemthing else.  Then you can make sure that your DC offsethits the middle of the range.  Stop guessing and start measuring.

Comment: @JRE I don't have an oscilloscope, thats my biggest drawback. I Guess I need to get one. See what I did there? hehe... I have a voltmeter, could you give me a simple instruction on how to measure the DC offset with a voltmeter?

Comment: Simple enough.  Connect everything as though you were going to use it, but make sure there's no audio on the audio line in - it MUST be connected to with everything running, just no audio.  Measure the DC Voltage across C2 (4.7nF).  Also measure the DC voltage where it goes into the ADC (after the analog input multiplexer.)  Check the specs and actual diagram of the ADC - the specs should tell you the input range.  It may also depend on the reference voltage that the circuit delivers to the ADC, so check that too.

Comment: @JRE DC voltage across C2 is 2.36, DC voltage where it goes in to the ADC is 2.36, Reference voltage is 5V, ADC input range is 5V. What else do I need to do?

Comment: @xaid: If you're referring to C2 in my drawing, that's about right.  What % of full scale does the ADC read?  Should be close to half-scale, but it's really hard to hit that exactly, which will appear in the FHT, hence my recommendation for a digital highpass before the FHT.

Comment: The next step beyond that, assuming the ADC reads correctly, is to put a predictable waveform into the audio in, like a sinewave, triangle, sawtooth, or similar.  Then record the waveform on the ADC (raw, not FHT) and compare to an oscilloscope.

Comment: Several years ago, I got a 4-channel 'scope on eBay for about $150 (US dollars) including probes and shipping.  You only need one channel for this if you move it around to different points in the circuit, but it's nice to have a few more.  A very good investment.

Comment: What does % of full scale mean? Please explain. Do you mean that if I feed ADC with 5 volt that it should read 1024 in the serial output? Likewise if I connect ground then the output should 0? If that is correct then I guess the % is 100% because 5 volt gives the value 1023 and ground gives the value 0.

Comment: If it's a 10-bit ADC, then full-scale is 1023 and so half-scale (50%) is 511.  If it's a 12-bit ADC, then full-scale is 4095 and so half-scale (50%) is 2047.  If your reference voltages are +5V and 0V, then full-scale would be +5V and 0 would be 0V, but there are lots of ADC's that use different references than the power supplies.

Comment: You want the analog highpass to read close to half-scale (50%) with no signal.  It doesn't have to be exact because you'll fix that with a digital highpass, but the farther off you are, the easier it is to clip.

Comment: According to the documentation of the chip I'm using, the ADC has 10 bit resolution. View page 317, 29.8: http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet.pdf

Comment: OK.  Things are a bit clearer.  The ADC will give you values that represent voltage between 0 and 5V.  Your AC is riding on a DC voltage of 2.36. An FFT of that signal will have a big hump at low frequencies.  You need to make it so that the sampled values are centered around 0.  Do this: 1) Change R1 (a little lower, around 9K) so that the measured DC voltage is exactly 2.5V. 2) Subtract the value that the ADC gives you for 2.5V from the incoming values.  This should minimize the "hump" at low frequencies.  You might be able to implement a highpass filter instead of doing the subtraction.

Comment: Actually, the simplest implementation of a highpass that I can think of right now is a subtraction, where the value to subtract is determined by an exponential average lowpass.

Comment: I would approach this slightly differently, though JRE's should also work.  I would see what the ADC tells me, and adjust the circuit so that the ADC reads close to half-scale.  This could be slightly different from half-supply.  Then account for the remaining error in software like JRE said.

Comment: Ok I tried changing the R1 value, it made the peak larger.
When reading the ADC with no signal it hovers around half scale, 450 something, while half scale is around 511. So I guess its Ok, right?
Regarding the High Pass Filter, since I need to detect low frequencies, wouldnt that counteract what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Not if you set if low enough.  The analog highpass (C1,R1,R2) is set for about 1.5Hz as I've drawn it.  If your digital highpass is there or lower, it should make very little difference except to remove the DC offset.

Comment: should we try a sightly larger value? Say 25Hz?

Comment: This kind of filter is very simple to make, but it has a fairly wide range of frequencies that it doesn't let through completely but doesn't really get rid of either.  So it's typically set well away from the frequencies of interest so that it doesn't mess them up.  That being said, the 1.5Hz number is an available-components approximation to 2Hz, which is a decade below 20Hz, which is the traditional lower limit for audio in general.  You can plug your own numbers in there and change the circuit accordingly.

Comment: I'll just have to wait until next week until I acquire an oscilloscope and some more components to try this out further. I don't understand what is has to be this difficult.

Comment: I think a big part of your difficulty is trying to make everything work at once.  You built the entire project before testing anything and now "something" doesn't work.  Every time I've done that, I ended up redoing everything because I acted on a simple misunderstanding early on, which caused more errors in everything that depended on that part.  I took it all apart again until it did very little, correctly, then rebuilt it step-by-step, testing along the way this time.  So all the work that went into the first version accomplished nothing except education in how not to do it.

Comment: @AaronD you are correct, that is one of my biggest problems, and I admit it. I got some good news though. I beleive your diagram is correct, and I changed something in software, which is to use Lin8 spectrum instead of Log, and that fixed everything with the peak and all. So now it is nice and dandy and I can read the frequencies perfectly. Maybe try to add in the answer that using a different method other than Log as the parameter?

Comment: @xaid: I think you still have a problem in terms of contaminating the signal; the linear scale just makes it harder to see that.  But depending on what you're actually doing with it, it might be good enough.  As a final display, the log scale would be much more useful, but if you're triggering something else, it's probably the same numbers behind the scenes regardless of scale.

Comment: @AaronD I believe it's good enough. the noise is barely visible, the kick jumps above 128 in value. That's all I really need. Quite frankly I'd like to broaden the resolution in the lower region of the frequency spectrum, so that the kick could be distinguished further, but hey, after over a week of constant testing and guessing and what not, I guess I can't ask for more than this, for now, at least. Thank you for your effort I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to help!  .